# callback error on second click

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

Everything is executing fine on first run. But, it gives the callback already called error on the second run. Thanks.

Server Side Code:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(pcallback) {
        //var mykeyword = "";
        //resultset="";

        app.post('/login',function(req,res){
        Keyword=req.body.keyword;
        Category=req.body.category;
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9000'); // Website you wish to allow to connect
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // Request methods you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); // Request headers you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)

        console.log("\nKeyword = "+Keyword+", Category is "+Category); //till here everything is executing fine on 2nd run
        //mykeyword=user_name;
        res.end("yes");
        pcallback(null, Keyword);
    });



    },
    function(mykeyword, pcallback) {

        Keyword=mykeyword;
        console.log("\n\nmy keyword ",Keyword)
        callAWS(Keyword, function(response){
            // Here you have access to your variable
            console.log(response);
            pcallback(null,response);
        })

    }, function(resultset, pcallback){
        app.use(function (req, res) {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9000/data'); // Website you wish to allow to connect
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // Request methods you wish to allow
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); // Request headers you wish to allow
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
            //console.log(resultset)
            //res.send(resultset)
            //console.log(resultset);
            res.send(resultset)
            res.end();
        });
        pcallback();
}], function(err){
    if(err) return(pcallback(err));
    console.log("I'm Done !");
});
```

From client side, I've a text box and a button which queries a certain keyword.

[image: error details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what's wrong:

When you (first) execute `async.waterfall(...)` 
you register a route for **POST /login**, and in your route handler you call pcallback() **every time** someone posts to `/login` :

```
async.waterfall([
    function(pcallback) {
       // ...
       app.post('/login',function(req,res){ 
          // ... 
          pcallback(null, Keyword);  // <= bug is here
          // ...
```

`async.waterfall` expects every callback to be called only once, so the first time a client posts - everything "works", but when a second POST comes along you call pcallback() again unexpectedly.

I'm not sure of what you intended doing, but I think the fix **might** be moving your entire `async.waterfall()` code inside the `app.post('/login',function(req,res){ });` handler, instead of having it the other way around.

Something like this (if I understood currently):

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    Keyword=req.body.keyword;
    Category=req.body.category;
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9000'); // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)

    console.log("\nKeyword = "+Keyword+", Category is "+Category); //till here everything is executing fine on 2nd run
    //mykeyword=user_name;
    res.end("yes");

    // pcallback(null, Keyword); <== pcallback() was HERE before
    async.waterfall([
        function(pcallback) {
            // Keyword=mykeyword;
            console.log("\n\nmy keyword ",Keyword)
            callAWS(Keyword, function(response){
                // Here you have access to your variable
                console.log(response);
                pcallback(null,response);
            })

        }, function(resultset, pcallback){
            app.use(function (req, res) {
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9000/data'); // Website you wish to allow to connect
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // Request methods you wish to allow
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); // Request headers you wish to allow
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
                //console.log(resultset)
                //res.send(resultset)
                //console.log(resultset);
                res.send(resultset)
                res.end();
            });
            pcallback();
        }], function(err){
        if(err) return(pcallback(err));
        console.log("I'm Done !");
    });

});
```

---

Also, I suspect you might have another hidden bug, in your last handler:

Your handler is

```
function (err) {
    if (err) return (pcallback(err));
    console.log("I'm Done !");
}
```

but there isn't any `pcallback` parameter (and there shouldn't be one), so unless you're referring to another `pcallback` hidden above this snippet, you'll probably get an exception when you actually have an err there.

Hope this helps :)